# Dialog Date Picker - Add save event

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm trying to use date dialog picker in my android project on a button. I have the dialog showing with no issues, however I don't know how to set a positive response button (i.e. the save event)

Here is my code:

```
public void addInstallDate(View view){
        Log.e("Showing Dialog", "Dialog Date");

                DatePickerDialog dateDlg = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                        {
                           Time chosenDate = new Time();
                           chosenDate.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
                           long dtDob = chosenDate.toMillis(true);
                           CharSequence strDate = DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", dtDob);


                       }}, 2011,0, 1);
                     dateDlg.setMessage("Install Date?");


 dateDlg.show();
        }
```

How do I set an onclick event for the two buttons that appear? - And once I've got the onclick, how do I grab the date its set?

Tom